# Spring Boot REST service returning 406 if configured behind Zuul Proxy

Tags: netflix-zuul

I have a Spring Boot REST-based GET service, to which I added a Zuul service proxy. Without Zuul proxy it works fine, but with zuul proxy I get a 406 error. I get the same error in both localhost and in Pivotal Cloud Foundry.

Below are the properties I set in Zuul proxy server. Have I made any mistakes?

```
zuul.routes.trustservice.url=http://localhost:8085
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
server.port=8765
```

[image: Failure response with zuul proxy app]

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine actually the issue was with Chrome giving cache issues with Get service. Once I cleared the cache and closed the browser and reopened then it is all hunky dory[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGKLU.png).